# how to get the profile of a user we click on?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I made this blog and I want to when click on a user's profile from any post the website goes to that specific use's profile I mean the one who wrote the post but right now I can only get the profile picture of the current logged in user what should I do? if I need to post more code please let me know

Thanks in advance

my profile page

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}

<div class="frame">
  <div class="center">
    
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="image">
                <div class="circle-1"></div>
                <div class="circle-2"></div>
                <img src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" width="70" height="70">
            </div>
            
            <div class="name">{{ post.author }}</div>
            <div class="job">Visual Artist</div>
            
            <div class="actions">
                <button class="btn">Follow</button>
                <button class="btn">Message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="stats">
            <div class="box">
                <span class="value">523</span>
                <span class="parameter">Posts</span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="value">1387</span>
                <span class="parameter">Likes</span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="value">146</span>
                <span class="parameter">Follower</span>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```html
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import post
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from users.models import Profile

  



def detail(request, id):
     poost = get_object_or_404(post, pk=id)
     return render(request, "posts/detail.html", {"post": poost})

@login_required()
def delete(request, id):
     poost = get_object_or_404(post, pk=id)
     if request.user == post.author:
          poost.delete()
          messages.error(request, f'Post deleted!')
          return redirect("/")



def side_bar(request):
      return render(request, "posts/sidemenu.html")



def userinfo(request):
    return render(request, 'posts/prof.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now clicking on the image of `{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}` leads you to the image itself. If you want to lead the user to some different url while displaying the image you would want to wrap the image in an a-tag.

```html
<a href="{% url 'AppWithAuthor:author-profile-view' author.id %}">
  <img src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" width="70" height="70">
</a>
```

`AppWithAuthor` replace with your app containing the url to the profile of an author 
`author-profile-view` replace with the name of the view to the profile of an author. You define this in urls.py 
`author.id` replace with the foreignkey of the author.

The discrepancy that it does not lead you to the post's author profile but to the profile of the user requires us to see the view function of views.py that renders the template you've shown in your question. Most likely though your currently logged in user is actually also the author of the post. Please recheck that.

Comment: thank you for your answer I updated the question and added views.py please check it out and no the current user I am logged in with is not the author of the post and I still can't get any of the author's information

Comment: Also I already can go to the url of the profile page just the profile page is not for the author I clicked at I can only give the current logged in user information to it

Comment: You still fail to show the view that displays the profile of user/author. You only posted irrelevant views. Please show the view that provides the variables for the author-profile and in the end renders the html-template you display in your question.

Comment: I edited the question this one renders my profile page but if there is any other problem please let me know

Comment: Still none of shown view functions render an author profile page. They render a post-detail (not author detail), a sidemenu and a post/prof. Although you import 'Profile' at the top, you are nowhere using it.

Comment: I have another profile page which is where users can go and edit their profile it's not public to see I wanted this part to be like when people click on the profile picture of an author which is on their post they get redirected to a profile info page which everybody can see now considering that which part of my code should i post?

Comment: Then you have to create a url, a view and a template for your wanted profile view. This is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views)