# How to get the profile picture of a user who is not logged in?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I made this user info page which is supposed to show the profile of the user you click on it is supposed to work even when the user is not logged in but I cannot get the username or profile picture of the user I chose I could only display the profile of the currently logged in user there what should I do??

if I need to post another page please let me know \

Thanks in advance

prof.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class="frame">
  <div class="center">
    
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="image">
                <div class="circle-1"></div>
                <div class="circle-2"></div>
                <div style="margin-left: -20px">
                <img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" width="110" height="110">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 30px"></div>
            <div class="name"> {{ user.username }} </div>
            <div class="job">Visual Artist</div>
            
            
            <div class="actions">
                <button class="btn">Follow</button>
                <button class="btn">Message</button>
            </div>

            <div class="sociic">
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}"><i class="fa fa-telegram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
            </div>

        </div>
        
        <div class="stats">
            <div class="box">
                <span class="value">523</span>
                <span class="parameter">Stories <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="value">1387</span>
                <span class="parameter">Likes <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="value">146</span>
                <span class="parameter">Follower <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>



<style>
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600,300);
 .frame {
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#EEBE6C', endColorstr='#CA7C4E',GradientType=1);
     font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
     -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
 .center {
     position: absolute;
     top: 136px;
     left: 325px;
     height: 470px;
     width: 700px;
     background: #fff;
     border-radius: 3px;
     box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
 .profile {
     float: left;
     width: 200px;
     height: 320px;
     text-align: center;
}
 .profile .image {
     position: relative;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     left: 50px;
     margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
}
 .profile .image .circle-1, .profile .image .circle-2 {
     position: absolute;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     width: 120px;
     height: 120px;
     top: -3px;
     left: -6px;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: #00aef3 #00aef3 #00aef3 transparent;
     border-radius: 50%;
     transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
     margin-left: -19px;
     margin-top: -2px;
     
}
 .profile .image .circle-2 {
     width: 130px;
     height: 130px;
     top: -7px;
     left: -10px;
     border-color: #00aef3 transparent #00aef3 #00aef3;
     margin-left: -20px;
     margin-top: -3px;
}
 .profile .image img {
     display: block;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: #f5e8df;
}
 .profile .image:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .profile .image:hover .circle-1, .profile .image:hover .image .circle-2, .profile .image .image:hover .circle-2 {
     transform: rotate(360deg);
}
 .profile .image:hover .circle-2 {
     transform: rotate(-360deg);
}
 .profile .name {
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: 600;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-left: 60px;
}
 .profile .job {
     font-size: 15px;
     line-height: 20px;
     margin-left: 60px;
}
 .profile .actions {
     margin-top: 25px;
}
 .profile .actions .btn {
     display: block;
     width: 120px;
     height: 30px;
     margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
     background: none;
     border: 1px solid #00aef3;
     border-radius: 15px;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: 600;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
     color: #00aef3;
     margin-left: 70px;
}
 .profile .actions .btn:hover {
     background: #9de8ff;
     color: #fff;
}
 .stats {
     float: left;
}
 .stats .box {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     width: 500px;
     height: 156px;
     background: #f5e8df;
     border-left: 80px solid white;
     text-align: center;
     padding-top: 55px;
     transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
 .stats .box:hover {
     background: #e1cfc2;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .stats .box:nth-child(2) {
     margin: 1px 0;
}
 .stats span {
     display: block;
}
 .stats .value {
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: 600;
}
 .stats .parameter {
     font-size: 16px;
}
 .sociic{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #00aef3;
}
 
</style>



{% endblock %}
```

UPDATE views.py

```
User = get_user_model()

def users_list(request):
  users = User.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'posts/prof.html', context={'users': users})
```

def user_info(request, id):
user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=id)
return render(request, 'posts/prof.html', context={'user': user})

UPDATE urls.py

```
 path('users/<int:id>', views.user_info, name='user_info'),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the profile of a user we click on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77624217/how-to-get-the-profile-of-a-user-we-click-on)

Answer (score 1):

You should fetch the users first in the view and then deliver the data to your template.

```
def userinfo(request):
    users = get_user_model().objects.all()
    return render(request, 'posts/prof.html', context={'users': users})
```

and then get the users and its data using a `for loop` in your template.

```
{% for user in users %}
<div class="frame">
  <div class="center">
    
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="image">
                <div class="circle-1"></div>
                <div class="circle-2"></div>
                <div style="margin-left: -20px">
                <img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" width="110" height="110">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 30px"></div>
            <div class="name"> {{ user.username }} </div>
            <div class="job">Visual Artist</div>
            
            
            <div class="actions">
                <button class="btn">Follow</button>
                <button class="btn">Message</button>
            </div>

            <div class="sociic">
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}"><i class="fa fa-telegram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
            </div>

        </div>
        
        <div class="stats">
            <div class="box">
                <span class="value">523</span>
                <span class="parameter">Stories <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="value">1387</span>
                <span class="parameter">Likes <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="value">146</span>
                <span class="parameter">Follower <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT:

Supposing you want the view for a user you click in, the logic changes to:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

User = get_user_model()

def users_list(request):
   users = User.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'posts/prof.html', context={'users': users})

def user_info(request, id):
   user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
   return render(request, 'posts/user_info.html', context={'user': user}
```

The view to call when you click a user is the user_info view, which url should include the id parameter:

```
path('users/<int:pk>/', user_info)
```

Comment: in view.py it says `"get_user_model" is not defined Pylance` what do I do?

Comment: you need to import it first
`from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`

Comment: it works but it gets a random user's information how can i pass in the id of the user?? I want it to show the one I clicked on

Comment: i edited the answer, not sure the structure you are looking for but hopefully you can use the logic

Comment: Thank you so much for your time just one more thing it does not show my template now I corrected the name too but it just shows a blank page

Comment: edit the question with the views and urls

Comment: I updated the codes please check it out as I said it does not show my template

Comment: add print statements to see if you are retrieving correctly the data in your view. print(users) or print(user). then add non dynamic components to your template to assure it is rendering the path correctly.